# Counting Hex in Assembly

Tags: assembly, hex

Im wondering, how does the hex system work in assembly?

Lets say I have:
0xFF,
0xAB,
0x10C,
0XA,
0XFC.
I have an example where 4 + 0xFC = 0xFF
Can someone explain for me what each letter and number means and how it is calculated?

Comment: I'll point out, that the neat thing about it too, is the ease with which we can convert a binary number to a hex one. There's 2 hex digits (nibbles) per byte and 4 bits per nibble. It's very easy to turn 0xC7 into 1100-0111b or vise versa - Turning 199 decimal into either is considerably more difficult in one's head. This can help explain why one sees hex digits used so often in programming

Answer (score 2):

You are really asking how hexadecimal works.  The assembly aspect of it does not change anything.

In decimal, each digit goes from 0 to 9 (ten different values).

In hex, each digit goes from 0 to 9, then to A, then B, C, D, E, and F (16 different values).

In both, the upper digits increment when the digit to its right carries one.

By the way, 4 + 0XFC is 0x100.

Answer (score 0):

Your information `4 + 0xFC = 0xFF` is wrong: `4 + 0xFC = 0x100`.

Taking the hexadecimal number `0xFC`, the `0x` is just a cue that it is a hex number - it does not form part of its value `FC`. There are other ways to express, it depends on the syntax in force. Some assemblers will want `0FCh`, in this case the `h` tells a hex number, and the leading `0` is to distinguish a *value* from the *label* `FCh`.

`A` to `F` represent the decimal values `10` to `15`, since the hexadecimal system is base 16 and our usual counting system is base 10, so lacks those single-digit values.

In a complementary way, the octal number system is base 8, so our well known decimal digits `8` and `9` are not used. Let's look at that representation first , because it's hard to talk in hexadecimal without getting confused by decimal.

Octal works in the same way as other number base systems. Taking `**` to mean "raised to the power",  octal `74` means `7 x 8**1 + 4 x 8**0`. In this case `8` is easy to understand, but doesn't actually exist in the octal system. It's represention in octal is `10`, so I *should* have written  `7 x 10**1 + 4 x 10**0`

Let's look at some additions. In decimal

```
 96 +
  4
--- 
100 (decimal)
```

because `6 + 4` generates a carry and so does `9 + carry`. In the same way in octal

```
 74 +
  4
--- 
100 (octal)
```

because `4 + 4` generates a carry and so does `7 + carry`.

Hex works in the same way too, but it's diffcult to describe because we lack 6 fingers to count with. The number `FC` means `F x 10**1 + C x 10**0`. In this case `10` is the hexadecimal format of decimal `16`. Expressed as decimal it is `15 x 16**1 + 12 x 16**0`.

Now for the hexadecimal sum you were incorrectly advised on.

```
 FC +
  4
---
100 (hexadecimal)
```

because `C + 4` generates a carry and so does `F + carry`.

Hexadecimal has its basis in binary notation, since that's how computer arithmetic works. The decimal number `15` is binary `1111` and the decimal number `12` is binary `1100`. Hexadecimal is just a more convenient way to express binary, by taking binary digits (bits) 4 at a time. So here binary `1111` is hex `F` and binary `1100` is hex `C`. Putting them together, binary `11111100` is hex `FC`.

Hex *notation* (for that's all it is) is useful when larger values are seen. The human mind can't easily grasp long series of bits such as the 32 bit value `11011110101011011011111011101111` but in hex that's `DEADBEEF`.

It can take a little while to get used to hex notation, but after a while (as when learning a human language) you'll begin to *think* that way, rather than constantly translating to and fro.